# C# manejo de multiples puertos seriales

Tags: c#, puertos, com

tengo un PC que tiene varios puertos COM y necesito una asesoria de como manejar la comunicacion entre los puertos COM.

Explicare un poco sobre que trata el proyecto. Tengo varios equipos que reciben señales de ciertos dispositivos de seguridad industrial y estas son enviadas por sus respectivos puerto COM.

Tengo un equipo con varios puertos COM donde estan conectados cada uno de estos dispositivos, por lo que este equipo solo tiene como funcion recibir las señales respectivos.

Ahora les presento el programa:

```
// Se define un Form con tres objectos enunciados abajo
// Objeto: Textbox; Name: Historial
// Objeto: ComboBox; Name: PuertosCom
// Objeto: Button, Name: PuertoStatus

    private List<SerialPort> puertosSerial = new List<SerialPort>();

// este evento busca los puertos seriales

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] buscarCom = SerialPort.GetPortNames();

        Historial.Text = "Esperando señales ..." + Environment.NewLine;
        if (buscarCom != null)
        {
            PuertosCom.DataSource = buscarCom;
            foreach (string com in PuertosCom.Items)
            {
                puertosSerial.Add(new SerialPort
                {
                    PortName = com,
                    BaudRate = 9600,
                    Parity = Parity.None,
                    DataBits = 8,
                    StopBits = StopBits.One,
                    Handshake = Handshake.None,
                    ReadTimeout = 500,
                    WriteTimeout = 500
                });
            }
        }
        else
        {
            _ = MessageBox.Show("No hay puertos COM instalados en el equipo");
        }
    }
```

en que parte del codigo debo agregar el evento DataReceived?, es decir agregar la siguiente linea:

SerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(nombre_evento);

ademas, eso debe hacerse con cada puerto COM que he agregado a mi List?
ultima pregunta: este mismo evento se aplica para cada puerto COM que tiene el equipo?

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

El evento que mencionas es de la clase [`SerialPort`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport#events). Por lo tanto, deberías suscribir al evento de todas sus instancias.

Primero necesitas crear una función que será llamada cada vez que se produzca el evento con la forma del delegado [`SerialDataReceivedEventHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialdatareceivedeventhandler). Así:

```
void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e){
    ...
}
```

En segundo lugar, aprovecha el momento en que creas y configuras el objeto para suscribir a su evento:

```
var port = new SerialPort()
{
    PortName = com,
    BaudRate = 9600,
    Parity = Parity.None,
    DataBits = 8,
    StopBits = StopBits.One,
    Handshake = Handshake.None,
    ReadTimeout = 500,
    WriteTimeout = 500
};

port.DataReceived += DataReceivedHandler;
puertosSerial.Add(port);
```

En la documentación hay algunos [ejemplos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived#examples).

Comment: Lo veo, al handler lo coloco una vez creado el objeto SerialPort. La captura de los datos lo tengo claro; pero mi duda es la siguiente: con múltiples puertos COM que tengo y con la acciones de abrir y cerrar algún COM, el evento del DataReceived se ve afectado. Es decir, debo volver añadir el evento al reabrir el COM?

Comment: @LeonardoOliveros que quieres decir con reabrir el puerto?

Comment: En el objeto Button que escribí en el código hace la función de cerrar o abrir el puerto. Simplemente a través de la propiedad IsOpen abro o cierro el puerto. Mi duda es si cierro el puerto COM y lo vuelvo abrir debo volver a definir el evento DataReceived

Comment: @Leonardo `IsOpen` es de solo lectura. Para cerrarlo llamas a la función `Close`. Normalmente las clases que implementan `IDisposable` no te sirven más luego de llamar a la función `Close` o `Dispose` pero como `SerialPort` tiene un método `Open` creo que puedes seguir utilizando las instancias y no haría falta suscribir de nuevo al evento.